# Getting Duplicate Id values from XML

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get lists from an XML document. I need to create two lists from two different sections and then match the Id values in the document.
Here is my XML File

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
    <VehicleCollection>
        <ModelInfo>
            <Vehicle>
                <Id>101</Id>
                <Color>Red</Color>
                <Year>1987</Year>
                <Make>Saturn</Make>
                <Manufacturer>General Motors</Manufacturer>
            </Vehicle>
            <Vehicle>
                <Id>100</Id>
                <Color>Blue</Color>
                <Year>1998</Year>
                <Make>Saturn</Make>
                <Manufacturer>General Motors</Manufacturer>
            </Vehicle>
        </ModelInfo>
        <PriceInfo>
            <Vehicle>
                <Id>101</Id>
                <OriginalCost>11000</OriginalCost>
                <MarketValue>1200</MarketValue>
            </Vehicle>
            <Vehicle>
                <Id>100</Id>
                <OriginalCost>11000</OriginalCost>
                <MarketValue>3100</MarketValue>
            </Vehicle>
        </PriceInfo>
    </VehicleCollection>
</Root>
```

I want to make certain that the number of items in the PriceInfo section match the number of items in the ModelInfo section. I am using the code below to get lists.

```
  private static void PrintVehicleInfo(string fileName)
    {
        if (fileName != null)
        {
            var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            var vehicle = xDoc.Descendants("Vehicle").ToList(); //Culprit
            foreach (var v in vehicle)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v.Element("Id"));
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I create two separate lists from the XMl document? I get a single list in which the ID values are repeated. If I try to include the section name in code, it throws a runtime exception.

```
 var vehicle = xDoc.Descendants("ModelInfo/Vehicle").ToList();
OR
 var vehicle = xDoc.Descendants("ModelInfo//Vehicle").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more digging led me to the solution.

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
            XElement vehicleCollection = xDoc.Element("Root").Element("VehicleCollection").Element("ModelInfo");
            var vehicle = vehicleCollection.Descendants("Vehicle").ToList();
            foreach (var v in vehicle)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v.Element("Id"));
            }
            vehicleCollection = xDoc.Element("Root").Element("VehicleCollection").Element("PriceInfo");
            vehicle = vehicleCollection.Descendants("Vehicle").ToList();
            foreach (var v in vehicle)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(v.Element("Id"));
            }
```